# How can we remove header from csv being fetched via urllib.request.urlretrieve

Tags: python, python-3.x

Remove header in the below imported csv via `URLLIB.REQUEST.URLRETRIEVE`

**CODE:**

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database/downloads/diabetes.csv", FILE_DATA)
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'header'? Tried using an html parser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516982/import-kaggle-csv-from-download-url-to-pandas-dataframe)

Files from kaggle need an authentication and I'm not sure if you are doing it.

https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api

Regards.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers - and when the resource you link to is another SO question, vote to close the question as duplicate instead (or if you don't have enough rep yet, just mention it in a comment).