# Read zipped txt file as pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a zipped txt file as pandas dataframe. Though the format of file after unzipping is txt, but it contains comma separated values.

Following the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885175/read-a-zipped-file-as-a-pandas-dataframe), I used:

```
path = 'data_folder/data.2020.ZIP'
df = pd.read_csv(path, compression='zip', header=None, sep=',')
print(df.head())
```

But it is throwing this error:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 37 fields in line 23, saw 80

I am using python 3.6 with pandas version 0.24.2. Would upgrading pandas help?

Comment: check the `sep=','` in the txt file, as the error shows line 23 does not follow this separation.

Comment: @Himanshu yes, that's happening because initial rows contain less columns while later rows contain more. I tried using `usecols` argument but it didn't help

Comment: You should control the unzipped data. Showing here the first rows and the row 23 could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was happening because of irrregular number of columns in various rows, and since I don't want to drop any data, I used the `names` argument with maximum number of columns to fix the issue like so:

```
path = 'data_folder/data.2020.ZIP'
df = pd.read_csv(path, compression='zip', header=None, sep=',', names=range(80))
print(df.head())
```