# How to unzip without writing to disk?

Tags: python, pandas, python-zipfile

I have a zip archive `path_to_zip_file` in a read-only system. The tricky thing is that I need to unzip its content and open a CSV file `testfile.csv` that is included in the zip archive. **Please notice that the zip archive includes many different files, but I only want to take a CSV file from it.**
My goal is to get the content of this CSV file into pandas dataframe `df`.

My code is shown below. Is there any way to update it in such a way that it can be executed in a read-only system? In other words, how can I run it in memory without writing to disk?

```
import zipfile
import pandas as pd

path_to_zip_file = "data/test.zip"
directory_to_extract_to = "result"
with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)

csv_file_name = "testfile.csv"
df = pd.read_csv("{}/{}".format(directory_to_extract_to,csv_file_name), index_col=False)
```

Comment: did you have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885175/read-a-zipped-file-as-a-pandas-dataframe)? I don't know if it is possible to do it when there are several csv in one zip file though.

Comment: @Ben.T: I have a single CSF file in a ZIP archive, but there are also many non-CSV files there.

Comment: @Ben.T: Thanks, let me try this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`ZipFile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) on the already opened archive, we can do just that:

```
import zipfile
import pandas as pd

with zipfile.ZipFile("archive.zip") as archive:
    with archive.open("testing.txt") as csv:
        df = pd.read_csv(csv)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do it is to extract it to /tmp, which is a directory in RAM. You could also use python's [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) library to create a temporary directory and extract it there (it will probably just create a directory in /tmp)

Comment: The code runs on Linux system. Is it "/tmp"?

Comment: Yes it is. I assumed it was linux since you were talking about a read only filesystem and using '/' as path separators